# How to identify entity framework work flow used in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC, I received a project from my client, the project is build on MVC, I am unable to identify what approach as been used to in the application. Whether it's  code first approach or a database first approach. How to identify it. The developer who designed the project is no more associated with the company so I can't seek his help.

Answer (score 1):

It will be database first if there is an [name].edmx diagram file and some templates (.tt). You can also search for `onModelCreating` and see if it has the statement `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` which would also indicate it is database first with an edmx.

Also, if it is EF Core it will be Code First.

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

Comment: That indicates Database First.